# Randomly reading structs from a binary file

Tags: c#, file, random, struct, binary

Hello to all the members,

I have the following struct:

```
public struct IncomeTax
{
    public string name, category;
    public int income;
}
```

I'm writing a no. of such structs(records) in binary format to text file using the following code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\\Hello.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);

BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
bw.Write(it.name);
bw.Write(it.category);
bw.Write(it.income);
bw.close(); 

fs.close();
```

Now, I want to randomly read records from this file, say I want to go to the 3rd record directly. I know that this can be done using `BinaryReader` & `FileStream.Seek`. But I don't know how to use `FileStream.Seek` to go directly to any record. Please help.

Answer (score 6):

You can't, with the structure you've got - the records could be any size. In order to seek to an arbitrary record, you *either* need to have a fixed size of record (which would mean having some limit on the size of your `name` and `category` strings, and then padding the records with empty space if they're smaller than that limit) *or* you need to build up a separate index, which would basically be fixed-sized records saying "record X starts at position Y".

Note that the latter approach makes *editing* a record tricky, as unless the new version is exactly the same size as the old one, you either need to keep it in place but "waste" some space at the end of the record, or create a new record at the end of the file.

**Or** you could just use a database, which is almost certainly a better idea. There are various forms of "embedded" database which means you wouldn't need a client-server config, just a file or two for the database contents.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your quick reply.I will make it a fixed size record by keeping size limit on "name" & "category" strings.

Comment: @RuchirSharma: Note that the size limit is in terms of the *bytes* you'll end up writing - so you'll either need to use a fixed-size encoding (e.g. UTF-16) or just limit the encoded size, leaving the size in *characters* variable; that could be confusing to callers, mind you...

Comment: I realize it's a parenthetical remark, but in context it is worth noting that UTF-16 is a variable-size encoding. UCS-2 is a fixed-size (2 bytes/char) subset of UTF-16, which cannot encode all Unicode code points. UTF-32 (4 bytes/char) is a fixed-size encoding that can encode all Unicode code points. That being said, I recommend always sticking to UTF-8 :)

Comment: @MagnusHoff: If we were talking about proper Unicode, I'd agree - but as .NET strings are sequences of UTF-16 code units, the size of a string written out in UTF-16 is exactly twice the `Length` property of the string. As that's how you'd probably end up enforcing a limit, it works in this case...

Comment: Aha :) That's a reasonably specific meaning of "fixed-size encoding" that I wasn't aware of. But as you say; the relevant meaning for this context.

Comment: @RuchirSharma: Still doesn't sound like a great idea compared with just using a database, to be honest...

Comment: @JonSkeet One more question sir: do we have a method in C# like the fread in C(just curious) ?

Comment: @RuchirSharma: With unsafe code you may be able to, but IMO it's a bad idea anyway - dumping the contents of memory, and being at the mercy of the exact representation in memory leads to a really fragile system.